# Math.toIntExact((long) value & 0xFFFFFFFFL) integer overflow

Tags: java, integer-overflow

I was shown this arbitrary piece of code and I think it serves no purpose since when I tried to run it, any time I pass in a negative number for the `value` to actually satisfy the if statement I get an `ArithmeticException: integer overflow`.

Is there any values I can actually pass into `value` such that the if statement is satisfied and `Math.toIntExact((long)value & 0xFFFFFFFFL)` doesn't throw an error?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    if (value < 0){
        int result = Math.toIntExact((long)value & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `value` is a negative int, then `(long)value & 0xFFFFFFFFL` will certainly be a positive long greater than int's maximum value.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed pointless. It looks like it's trying to get an "unsigned int" which Java doesn't support. You really only have to options: 1. store the value in a `long` instead of an `int` or 2. keep it in an `int` and make sure to never use it in a way where the  signed-ness would be relevant (i.e. always use specific unsigned maths methods or formatting methods).

Comment: The specific unsigned methods @JoachimSauer mentioned can be found in the `Long` or `Integer` class, i.e. `Long.parseUnsignedLong()` or `Long.toUnsignedString()`. There are more utilities, like unsigned compare, divide or remainder. And all these methods also exists on the `Integer` class

Comment: Thanks @Lino, I knew they existed but since I never had to use them myself I didn't know where ;-)

Comment: Practically the code looks for having  `System.out.println(value);System.out.println(Integer.toUnsignedString(value));` inside that `if`.